# Handling InputBox error as a result of feeding bad data or cancellation

Tags: vba, excel

What is the smartest way to handle `Inputbox` when it comes to deal with any error occurring as a result of pressing the `OK` button without feeding anything or pressing the `Cancel` button or any bad data input except for the condition given in my script.

```
Sub Inputbox_Clarity()
    Dim feeding As String

    feeding = InputBox("Enter something you wish or do whatever")
    If feeding < 1000 Or feeding > 3000 Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = feeding
End Sub
```

Comment: Just type `On Error Resume Next` before `feeding` declaration and you are safe. If you want to deal with a specific error, for example type error( which is number 13), you can insert a condition after `feeding` declaration like `If Err.Number = 13 Then..`

Comment: @Dominic, Did you mean to change this line to `If Len(feeding) < 1000 Or Len(feeding) > 3000 Then Exit Sub` and keep the rest as it is, right?

Comment: Thanks Tehscript, for your solution but I do not wish to comply `On Error Resume Next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I make change to the variable `feeding` from `String` to `Variant` then it can handle any error irrespective of it's type. Here it is.

```
Sub Inputbox_Clarity()
    Dim feeding As Variant

    feeding = InputBox("Execution won't take place until the input is between 1000 to 3000")
    If feeding < 1000 Or feeding > 3000 Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = feeding
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little sample:

```
Sub Inputbox_Clarity()
    Dim feeding As Variant

    feeding = InputBox("Enter something you wish or do whatever")

    If feeding = "" Then
        MsgBox "you entered nothing or touched cancel or clicked the red x"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not IsNumeric(feeding) Then
        MsgBox "you gave me a non-numeric"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If feeding < 1000 Or feeding > 3000 Then
        MsgBox "you gave me out-of range"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = feeding
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student, for your solution. It works. +1 for this. However, i have found a more concise and dynamic one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the InputBox function, another approach would be to use the InputBox method of the Application object, which contains built-in error handling.

```
Sub Inputbox_Clarity()
    Dim feeding As Variant
    feeding = Application.InputBox("Enter a number >= 1000 and <= 3000", "Number", Type:=1)
    If feeding = False Then Exit Sub
    If feeding < 1000 Or feeding > 3000 Then Exit Sub
    ActiveSheet.Range("A100") = feeding
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can use a Do/Loop to continue prompting for a valid number or until the Cancel button is pressed.

```
Sub Inputbox_Clarity()
    Dim feeding As Variant
    Do
        feeding = Application.InputBox("Enter a number >= 1000 and <= 3000", "Number", Type:=1)
        If feeding = False Then Exit Sub
    Loop While feeding < 1000 Or feeding > 3000
    ActiveSheet.Range("A100") = feeding
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!